# Nexus 4 screen goes blank while there is an incoming call

Tags: nexus-4, calls, reboot

I am using Nexus 4 running on Kitkat 4.4.4 and facing a weird issue since a few days.

- Whenever there is an incoming call, I can only hear the ringtone/vibrations but no display.
- If I press the power button, I can not see the incoming call screen. So, I can not receive the call at all, even if I unlock the screen.
- After this, if I try to call back, the outgoing call screen is not seen but the call goes through and I can continue with the call - but without the outgoing call screen. That means, I can not hang up the call if the phone is only ringing on the other side.
- This behavior is random but frequent. After a reboot, everything comes back to normal.

Any way out to stop this? Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact solution for this issue was not found. This is not happening after I have updated my phone to Lollipop.